# How to perform NSDecimal Math?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, nsdecimal

I am attempting to perform basic NSDecimal math such as addition multiplication and subtraction of NSDecimals. Is this possible to accomplish?
trying to use NSDecimalAdd
getting error

NSDecimal' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSDecimal * _Nonnull'

```
_meat.colonyQueenObject.count.creatureCount = [colonyQueenNumber decimalValue];


-(void)adjustCountsCreatureCountforAddedCreatures:(NSDecimal)creaturesAdded meatCount:(NSDecimal)meatCount larvaCount:(NSDecimal)larvaCount creatureType:    (int)creatureType{

    NSDecimalAdd(_meat.colonyQueenObject.count.creatureCount, _meat.colonyQueenObject.count.creatureCount, &creaturesAdded, NSRoundBankers);


    }


   NSDecimalAdd(&_meat.colonyQueenObject.count.creatureCount, &_meat.colonyObject.count.creatureCount, &creaturesAdded, NSRoundBankers);
```

also fails

Comment: Are you using `NSDecimal` or `NSDecimalNumber`?

Comment: NSDecimal I need mutable numbers

Comment: `NSDecimal` is just a structure. To add two `NSDecimal`s you would call the `NSDecimalAdd` function. To multiply, there's another function. I'll let you guess what that's called.

Comment: @user3386109 i can't seem to get the function to work would you mind taking a look at my updated question

Comment: I think all you need is a couple more ampersands `&`.

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't need mutable `NSDecimal`. Almost always you should use `NSDecimalNumber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDecimal` is a *value type*; just like `int`, `float`, etc. However the math functions, such as `NSDecimalAdd`, take their arguments and return their result *by address* - that is the arguments & result must be *variables* passed by address, obtained using the `&` operator, to the function and not by value.

Your second attempt:

```
NSDecimalAdd(&_meat.colonyQueenObject.count.creatureCount,
             &_meat.colonyObject.count.creatureCount,
             &creaturesAdded,
             NSRoundBankers);
```

is the closest to being correct, but the first two arguments are incorrect as you are attempting to pass the address of a *property* - which is not possible. So you should be seeing an error like:

> Address of a property expression requested

If you wish to use properties you will have to use temporary intermediate local variables to hold your values. E.g. something along the lines of:

```
NSDecimal leftOperand = _meat.colonyObject.count.creatureCount; // copy left operand value to variable
NSDecimal result; // variable for result
NSDecimalAdd(&result,
             &leftOperand,
             &creaturesAdded,
             NSRoundBankers);
_meat.colonyQueenObject.count.creatureCount = result; // assign result to property
```

You should also be checking the return value of `NSDecimalAdd` as it indicates whether the operation was performed correctly (`NSCalculationNoError`).

HTH